# Метод коллекции BackboneJS для использования chaining

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, коллекции

Есть коллекция:

```
var Col = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: myModel,
  method_1: fucntion () { this.filter()},
  method_2: function () {this.filter()}
});
```

Есть необходимость использовать цепочки вызовов обоих методов, например:

```
var data = this.method_1().method_2();
```

Для этого, если я правильно понимаю, нужно чтобы методы возвращали `this`.

Но в то же время эти методы нужно использовать и вне цепочек. Например, вернуть отфильтрованные данные только после применения одного из методов.
Как вариант думал в метод передавать какой-то параметр-флаг: если метод использовать в цепочке, то возвращать this (но непонятно где хранить отфильтрованные данные и как их вернуть после цепочки вызовов), а если без цепочки - возвращать массив данных.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить такую задачу?

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о фильтрации то нужно возращать новую коллекцию содержащую результат фильтрации

```
var items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    grepByType: function(type){
        return new items(this.where({type: type}));
    },
    grepByUser: function(user){
        return new items(this.where({user: user}));
    }
});
```

Таким образом можно делать вызовы как цепочкой, так и получать результат, но уже не в виде массива а в виде Backbone#Collection-объекта